# Executing threads concurrently

Tags: multithreading, thread-synchronization

I am currently studying for my upcoming midterm and I am confused about this question which I have answered, but I am not completely sure if I answered it correctly:

Given two threads:

**Initially x = 0**

Thread 1: x = x+1

Thread 2: x = x + 2

What are the possible values of x in these cases?

My answer to this is **three** possible values:

If both of them do not run exactly at the same time, but in sequentially x can be 3. If they run at the same time then we get two values which is 1 and 2. Am I correct in this thinking? Since these are threads in the same process, I am thinking they share memory so that is also one of my reasoning.

Comment: The program could also terminate before one of them finishes leaving `x` as 1 or 2.

Comment: If x is a stack-based local, there are two 'x'.

Comment: You have a race condition. It's an undefined program unless you specify a programming language where these have defined behavior.

Comment: Consider that (assuming regular/non-atomic operations are used), (x=x+n) is implemented in three steps:  Step 1:  Read the current value of x from memory into a CPU register;   Step 2:  Increase the value in the CPU register by (n);   Step 3:  write the resulting (larger) value back out to memory.  Since no synchronization is being performed, thread A's steps 1-3 can potentially occur interleaved with thread B's steps 1-3 in a number of possible ways, with varying results.